# Delphi create dxTileBarItem runtime

Tags: delphi, devexpress, runtime

i used Delphi XE7 and DevExpress component, i need to create dxTileBarItem at runtime and add this to my dxTileBar but i cant.

```
  var
    //Tile4:TdxTileControlItem;
    Tile4:TdxTileBarItem;
  begin
    Tile4 := TdxTileBarItem.Create(dxTileBar1);
    Tile4.Name := 'Tile4';
    Tile4.GroupIndex := 0;
    Tile4.IndexInGroup := 3;
```

what is my mistake?
then i want to store a form object in manually created dxTileItem and call each from on OnTileClick such as ListBox, what do i should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **CreateItem** method, for example:

```
var
  MyTile: TdxTileBarItem;
begin
  MyTile := dxTileBar1.CreateItem(tbisRegular);
  MyTile.Name := 'My Tile';
  ...
end;
```

Or you can follow quite common pattern used by Delphi controls, add the item to the control's **Items** collection, for example:

```
var
  MyTile: TdxTileBarItem;
begin
  dxTileBar1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    MyTile := TdxTileBarItem(dxTileBar1.Items.Add);
    MyTile.Name := 'My Tile';
    ...
  finally
    dxTileBar1.EndUpdate;
  end;
  MyTile.MakeVisible;
end;
```